# Extremally disconnected sets as building blocks for compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, limits-and-colimits, compactness

Is every compact Hausdorff space the filtered colimit of compact extremally disconnected spaces?

Comment: Have you tried the bar resolution associated to the ultrafilter monad?

Comment: @AndréHenriques No I haven't: I will take a look at this and report back.

Comment: @AndréHenriques You may well be right, but I have not figured out how to extract a filtered colimit from a resolution.

Comment: You're right: It's only sifted. Not filtered.